# Adding Web API and folder references to empty ASP.NET project with Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to follow [this guide](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) in order to create a web API in an empty ASP.NET project. Upon creating the project, the author gets [an additional dialog](http://i2.asp.net/media/4410055/getstarted02.PNG?cdn_id=2013-11-14-001) that asks him if he wants folders and core references added for a couple of things, including Web API. I am not getting that option on Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web. All I'm getting is this dialog, which immediately creates the project upon being submitted:

[image]

How can I easily add all necessary references and folders to work with Web API? I am not looking at creating an MVC project, or anything else other than an empty ASP.NET project.

Comment: As far as I know, this option is only available in VS 2013 and not in previous editions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add it using a Nuget package. I think [this one](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/) or [this one that you have suggested](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/5.0.0) is what you will need.

Comment: I hadn't even though about looking in NuGet! Thank you. I ended up installing [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/5.0.0) (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core) which is exactly what I needed. If you wanted to edit your answer to reflect that package I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: I am not still getting additional dialog after first dialog for creating new project. I have installed Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core @AlexTurpin